Linux Mint 21.3 Cinnamon audio not working after a short time
I've recently upgraded to Linux Cinnamon 21.3 from a Linux Mint device (ASUS i think) and the sound has started crapping out after 30 minutes or so. It just abruptly stops with no apparent trigger. Does anyone know what's going on? Has this happpened to anyone else?
I've checked every app, other devices with the network, and using other networks. I've also refreshed and rebooted several times to no avail. I tried restarting the sound driver, but that did not work. Removing PulseAudio entirely caused errors that i had to restore to fix. There are also no major updates i need to install right now.
I also am hearing a lot of popping and crackling from my audio, does that pass? Or who should i call to fix it?
The following are my specs:

OS: Linux Mint 21.3 Cinnamon
Cinnamon version: 6.0.4
Linux Kernel: 5.15.0-119-Generic
Processor: Intel Core i3-5020U CPU @ 2.20GHz × 2
Memory: 3.7 GiB
Hard Drives: 1001.3 GB
Graphics Card: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500
Display Server: X11

Should i list my sound card or driver also?

Is there any syslog output before or at the time it stops that could give a clue? If so please include in your question. Could you also include output of: inxi -Fxxxrz

Try installing PipeWire. 
It has backwards compatibility with pavucontrol,
so I recommend trying that out as well.

Thanks! I installed it. If it works, i'll edit the OP.

It hasn't, I don't think. It didn't recognize some parts of Pipewire. I've heard something about my computer likely running an old version, but I wouldn't know how to update it properly.

Okay, now i have Pipewire. I now hear crackling leading to the audio giving out.
